# Change column value based on calculated mean of other column in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am newbie to pandas. I have gone through many questions, but doesn't found an answer.

I have the following datasets.

```
Name    || Price    || Cuisine Category || City || Region || Cuisine Types || Rating Types || Rating

Pizza  || 600  || Fast Food,Pizza || Ajmer ||   Ana Saga || Quick Bites || Good || 3.9

...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...

Chawla's || 300 || Beverages || Ajmer || Sagar Lake     || Cafe || Average || 3.3

Masala || 0 || North,South Indian || Ajmer || Ram Ganj || Mess || None || NEW
```

I want to change the value of:

- Rating where it is a NEW, on the basis of Average Rating of that particular Cuisine Types and then Rating Types based on the calculated Ratings
- Price where it is a 0, on the basis of Average Price of that particular Region

My try for changing price:

Reading CSV File

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/Ajmer.csv')
```

calculate Region wise mean of Price

```
gregion = round(data.groupby('Region')['Price'].mean())
```

Trying to replace 0 of price column

```
data['Price'] = data['Price'].replace(0, gregion[data['Region']])
```

But my price column is unchanged.

My try for changing Rating:

Reading CSV file

```
data2 = pd.read_csv('/content/Ajmer.csv')
```

Creating separate data frame, so that it wont affect mean value.

```
filtered_rating = data2[(data2['Rating'] == 'NEW') | (data2['Rating'] == '-') | (data2['Rating'] == 'Opening')]
```

Dropping from original data2

```
data2.drop(data2.loc[data['Rating']=='NEW'].index, inplace=True)
data2.drop(data2.loc[data['Rating']=='-'].index, inplace=True)
data2.drop(data2.loc[data['Rating']=='Opening'].index, inplace=True)
```

Calculating Cuisine Types wise mean of Rating

```
c = round(data2.groupby('Cuisine Types')['Rating'].mean(),1)
```

which gives me output as follows:

```
Cuisine Types

Bakery            3.4

Confectionery     3.4

Dessert Parlor    3.5

...

Quick Bites       3.4

Sweet Shop        3.4

Name: Rating, dtype: float64
```

Trying to replace values

```
filtered_rating['Rating'].replace('NEW', c[data2['Region']], inplace=True)
filtered_rating['Rating'].replace('-', c[data2['Region']], inplace=True)
filtered_rating['Rating'].replace('Opening', c[data2['Region']], inplace=True)
```

But my Rating column is unchanged.

Expected output

- Mean Price of that particular Region of row where the price is zero in Price column
- Mean Rating of that particular Cuisine Type of row where the Rating is NEW in Rating column

Can anyone help me out to do this?

Thanks in Advance!
I will be more than happy for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have a data like following.

```
data
    name            region     price    cuisine_type          rating_type   rating
0   pizza           NY          500      fast food              average        3.3
1   burger          NY          350      fast food              good           4.1
2   lobster         LA          1500     seafood                good           4.5
3   mussels         LA          1000     seafood                average        3.9
4   shawarma        NY          300    mediterranean            average        3.4
5   kabab           LA          600    mediterranean            good             4
6   pancake         NY          250      breakfast              average        3.7
7   waffle          LA          450      breakfast              good           4.2
8   fries           NY          0        fast food              None           NEW
9   crab            LA          0        seafood                None        Opening
10  tuna sandwich   NY          0        seafood                None           NEW
11  onion rings     LA          0        fast food              None        Opening
```

Now according to your question we need to replace the rating when it is NEW or Opening with mean rating of respective cuisine_type. And price when its 0 with mean price of respective region. And update rating type for None at the end.

```
#get a list of cuisine types
cuisine_type_list=data.cuisine_type.unique().tolist()

cuisine_type_list
['fast food', 'seafood', 'mediterranean', 'breakfast']

#get a list of regions
region_list=data.region.unique().tolist()

region_list
['NY', 'LA']
```

```
#replace the ratings 
for i in cuisine_type_list:
  data.loc[(data.cuisine_type==i) & (data.rating.isin(['NEW', 'Opening'])), 'rating']=round(data.loc[(data.cuisine_type==i) & (data.rating.isin(['NEW', 'Opening'])==False)].rating.mean(), 2)

#replace price when 0
for i in region_list:
  data.loc[(data.region==i) & (data.price==0), 'price']=round(data.loc[(data.region==i) & (data.price!=0)].price.mean(), 2)


#function to assign rating type (assuming good for rating>=4)
def calculate_rating_type(row):
  if row['rating'] >= 4:
    return 'good'
  else: 
    return 'average'

#update rating type
data.loc[data.rating_type.isnull(), 'rating_type']=data.loc[data.rating_type.isnull()].apply(lambda row: calculate_rating_type(row), axis=1)
```

this is the data after updating

```
data
    name            region     price    cuisine_type          rating_type   rating
0   pizza           NY          500      fast food              average        3.3
1   burger          NY          350      fast food              good           4.1
2   lobster         LA          1500     seafood                good           4.5
3   mussels         LA          1000     seafood                average        3.9
4   shawarma        NY          300    mediterranean            average        3.4
5   kabab           LA          600    mediterranean            good             4
6   pancake         NY          250      breakfast              average        3.7
7   waffle          LA          450      breakfast              good           4.2
8   fries           NY          350      fast food              average        3.7
9   crab            LA          887.5    seafood                good           4.2
10  tuna sandwich   NY          350      seafood                good           4.2
11  onion rings     LA          887.5    fast food              average        3.7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Brilliant way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
gregion = round(data.groupby('Region')['Price'].mean()) 
# convert your group by to DataFrame
gregion = pd.DataFrame(gregion)
gregion.reset_index(inplace=True)

# merge the datas and drop the new column that is created
data = data.merge(gregion, left_on='Region', right_on='Region', suffixes=('_x', ''))
data = data.drop(columns={'Price_x'})

filtered_rating = data[(data['Rating'] == 'NEW') | (data['Rating'] == '-') | (data['Rating'] == 'Opening')]

# you don't need to re-upload the file
data2 = data.copy()

data2.drop(data2.loc[data2['Rating']=='NEW'].index, inplace=True)
data2.drop(data2.loc[data2['Rating']=='-'].index, inplace=True)
data2.drop(data2.loc[data['Rating']=='Opening'].index, inplace=True)

# do the same with c
c = round(data2.groupby('Cuisine Types')['Rating'].mean(),1)
c = pd.DataFrame(c)
c.reset_index(inplace=True)

filtered_rating = filtered_rating.merge(c, left_on='Cuisine Types', right_on='Cuisine Types', how='left', suffixes=('_x', ''))
filtered_rating = filtered_rating.drop(columns={'Rating_x'})
```

Hope this helps.